# Scrolling fixed div with overflowing content on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a responsive website, and built a Facebook-like slider for mobiles. So I made a very plain setup, which works pretty neat so far. I'm having all content in a `.outer_wrapper` which fills the whole body. Under this wrapper is a `.slider` div with following CSS:

```
.slider {
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 250px;
}
```

when I press a trigger it shifts the `.outer_wrapper` to the left  and the `.slider` appears.

```
$('.hamburger-menu').click(function() { 
   $('.outer_wrapper').animate({marginLeft: '-250px', marginRight: '-250px'}, 'slow');
});
```

Problem is, that `.slider` has overflowing content, but on mobiles it refuses to scroll. It always scrolls the content of `.outer_wrapper`. I tried `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` and `overflow-y: scroll;`.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that `.slider` is not a child of `.outer_wrapper`. So my body is following structure:

```
<body>
  <div class=".outer_wrapper">
    <!-- all the lovely content is here -->
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <!-- some menu items here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Is this for mobile phone UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys a little update for that. I found out the issue came from a plugin I used by the name of [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr). When deactivating it:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

or

```
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

works just fine. To make it smoother on Webkit devices the following does an awesome job

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

The given case changes the entire question, which is why I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

what i would suggest, is to have `.slider` positioned outside `.outer_wrapper`. Then animate them both by toggling their class, and using css transforms. This way, they won't conflict with each other when the user swipes the page down.

Try this

```
 .slider {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:250px;
    top:0;
    left:0;

    -webkit-transform:translate(-250px,0px);
    transform:translate(-250px,0px);

    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
 }

 .slider.reveal {
      -webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);
      transform:translate(0px,0px);
 }


 .outer_wrapper {
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);
    transform:translate(0px,0px);

    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
 }


 .outer_wrapper.hide {
      -webkit-transform:translate(250px,0px);
      transform:translate(250px,0px);
 }
```

and for the Jquery, use the toggleClass function as follows:

```
 $('.hamburger-menu').click(function() { 
      $('.outer_wrapper’).toggleClass(‘hide’);
      $(‘.slider’).toggleClass(‘reveal’);
 });
```

Hopefully that helps?

Comment: I really appreciate your attempt to help. Unfortunately I should have mentioned that `.slider` is not child of `.outer_wrapper`. I did basically what you suggested, but with jQuery animations.

Comment: ah ok, sorry.
Weird as thats worked for me in the past pretty consistently.

What happens if you add de-activate scroll on the outer-wrapper, when the hamburger-menu is clicked?
i.e.
overflow-y:hidden;

and also make sure the z-index of the menu slider is greater than the outer-wrapper.

Comment: great idea with the `overflow-y: hidden;` on the wrapper. Will give that a try immediately. I have `z-index` in mind, and the issue does not come from that!

Comment: that didn't work, but it turned out the problem was something different in general. So this might be useful for someone else! Thank you for the help, appreciate!

Comment: ah ok. yes just saw your reply... Scrollr used to always give me problems on mobile. I stopped using it. found this excellent article on using pure CSS parallax which i have found its great on mobile. also easier to implement. http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/
Good luck with your site.

Comment: yeah its weird. And hacking a plugin around does not feel right! Will have a look at your link.